# Are click-to-edit fields appropriate for mobile UX?

Tags: mobile, mobile-web, mobile-application, mobile-text-entry

I have used click to edit fields for a html5 application which makes it slick to use on a desktop but I am not sure how the click-to-edit fields would be perceived by mobile users.  Would it be appropriate to use click-to-edit fields for a mobile application?

P.S. :To clarify, by click-to-edit, I mean fields that are displayed as text (with some visual clues to indicate they are editable). When clicked, the text changes to an input field and reverts back to text after the user is done making changes and focusses out.

See this fiddle here for examples : [JS FIDDLE WITH EXAMPLES OF CLICK-TO-EDIT FIELDS](http://jsfiddle.net/6gffg/1/)

Comment: What do you mean by "click-to-edit field"? A field displaying communicate "Click to edit" or something that  switches to edit mode *after* it is clicked and does not show this affordance before?

Comment: @DominikOslizlo, See my edited/updated question for clarification. I have also added a jsfiddle with examples. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks! I don't know if these will be less usable on mobile, but I think you should add some [Edit] button to the right. Dashed underline is not meaningful enough, it still looks like a link. Or, you can use text fields all the time, just alter them while in edit mode.

Answer (score 3):

I am looking and typing this on my Nokia Lumia.

Your JSfiddle looks and works ok. However you need to make it clear that this is a editing page. The way in which it is currently styled it looks more like links.

Comment: thanks for checking this out on the Lumia. Any suggestions/ideas on how visually clue in the user to the fact the fields are editable when clicked/touched, while still keeping a minimalist look? Adding text such as "click to edit this field" would clutter it up too much. On the desktop, I can add show a tooltip when the user hovers the mouse over the field, which should help make it clearer. However, on a mobile device, mouse-over/hover is not available, so it would need to be some other kind of visual clue.

Comment: I think as long as it's clear they are on a "Edit Your Account Preferences" page it will be self explanatory. If they are on a "Your Account Page" then simply include once "click an item to edit".

Comment: An additional reinforcement is for any fields where they haven't added anything perhaps in greyed out writing put "Tap to Add"

Answer (score 3):

It's probably workable, but note that a more typical UI is to have an 'edit' button that changes the page into an editable state as a whole. For example, on IOS:

[image]

My concern with tap-to-edit at the field level is that it could be a lot easier to select accidentally, which would trigger the keyboard, which could get annoying.

Comment: I have to say I think the user experience of iOS alarms is utterly awful. For a company that strives to minimise the number of clicks there is an awful lot here.

Comment: @tim.baker I don't think I'd disagree. That said, the screen was less about alarms and more about showing the somewhat common 'edit' button at the page level.

Comment: @DA01, thanks, your point about user expectations for an "edit" button on iOS is well taken. Is this UI approach also generally true of third-party apps on iOS? Opinions on how this compares to the norm on Android are also welcome.

Comment: @tim.baker, agree about number of clicks. Reducing clicks and UI buttons for a 'clean' look is one of the strong motivations for using click-to-edit, while at the same time, balancing it against established UI conventions and user expectations.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is the way to go on mobile because you are saving space and simplifying (if you have tested the functionality and it works). On mobile, people are learning more and more to tap to discover.

I would design the editable text to have a subtle flat button look, which would make it a bit more obvious. Or use a small edit icon.